# mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;

Tags: java, android, arrays, modulo

I don't understand the syntax of:

```
mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
```

(`mQuestionBank` is an array).

What is the reason for `% mQuestionBank.length`?

Answer (score 6):

It is logically equivalent to

```
if (mCurrentIndex + 1 < mQuestionBank.length) {
    mCurrentIndex++;
} else {
    mCurrentIndex = 0;
}
```

and used to rotate the index through the array without exceeding its bounds.

Comment: It would have been shorter to say `if (++mCurrentIndex == mQuestionBank.length) { mCurrentIndex = 0; }`. Still got my up-vote, though.

Answer (score 2):

`%` is the mod operator. This operator gives you the remainder after dividing the value before the `%` by the value after the `%`.

For example,

```
5 % 2 = 1
```

This is because when you divide 5 by 2, you get a remainder of 1.

Answer (score 2):

To access the elements of the array in a circular manner.

`mCurrentIndex` will always be bound between the range [0, `array.length`)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it's basic mod logic.

Essentially if you have a quiz with a limited amount of questions, you will loop through the quiz over and over with the mod.

For example lets assume you have an array with 4 questions.

It would be: 
    [0, 1, 2, 3].

Since you have 
    mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;

```
0%4 = 0 hence index 0, so it returns the question on index 0. 
1%4 = 1 hence index 1, so it returns the question on index 1. 
2%4 = 2
3%4 = 3
4%4 = 0
```

So it will never provide an index over 3.

Ex.

```
503%4 = 3
504%4 = 0
```

The app will continue to ask the same 4 questions in a loop. If you have more questions, then it will ask more.